# Is there a way of using the <prosody> tag in SSML to adjust individual words without a pause (without using a post-processor)

Tags: text-to-speech, ssml

When using the prosody tag in SSML with Google Cloud TTS, I cannot adjust the attributes of individual words without creating an unwanted pause.

The code below creates a lag between 'New' and 'Video'. It has been suggested that a postprocessor can remove these pauses, but I'd like to know if there's a way of doing it directly within the code itself?

```
<speak>

Hello, and welcome to this<prosody pitch="+3st">New</prosody>Video Tutorial.

</speak>
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing, it appears there isn't a way of doing this using Google Cloud TTS. You can manually edit the sound file after generating it, but thay defeats the object of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the cleanest answer, as what you are asking is not very supported. Prosody's pitch contour let's you change the tone of voice at different parts of the sentence.

**Example of Prosody contour**

```
<speak><prosody contour="(0%, +20Hz) (20%, +30%) (100%, +20%)"> Hello friends! </prosody></speak>
```

I am still playing around with this, but it seems like a tedious way of getting what you want done.

**Using contour**

contour takes a string of tuples "(%position in sentence, pitch adjustment) (..., ...)

*I hope this helped and best of luck on your work!*